# What is the glyphicons icon for resetting a form to its original values?

Tags: glyphicons

What is the glyphicons icon for resetting a form to its original values? I have looked at the cheat sheet, [Bootstrap Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/)
The "glyphicon-refresh" icon is the closest one I see.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for icons [here](http://glyphicons.com/): http://glyphicons.com/

This might be what you're looking for: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>`

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be one. I'm looking for the same thing myself.

Answer (score 0):

The one I'm using is `glyphicon-remove` since there isn't a specific one.

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
</div>
```